# How to make slight modifications to a WPF View based on some configuration

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, runtime

we have a MVVM application and a requirement saying (simplified for the example)  that based on the value of one int property we should make slight modifications to a View.

For example, if the property has a value of 1 we should change the background color of one View's button, if the value is 2 we should hide one `Label` and put in bold the text of a `TextBox`, if the value is 14 we should hide 2 `Labels`.

As the values could be decided after building the application we would like something like a file, an assembly loaded at runtime with reflection or whatever specifying what has to be done on the view without deploying the whole application.

The main idea is to create the View, put a name on all the available items and pass it to a class defined in an assembly loaded at runtime that will know what to do with the View. The problem we see with this approach is that you need to define names for everything on the View.

Do you think is there a better approach to fulfill the requirement? The changes to do on the View will be always just a few properties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a shame that the values could be created at run time because otherwise, you could just have set up `Binding`s to your `int` property to do it all automatically.

Comment: if you need totally dynamic UI, and decision will be taken after app has been build/deployed you can also use dynamic xaml - I mean define view(parts of view)  in the xaml which should be loaded using XamlReader at runtime. So you can later modify this xaml using another app, or dll loaded in runtime.

Comment: @Sheridan: agree, in that case the solution would be easy :(

Comment: @vitaliyzadorozhnyy: the thing is that we need just to modify an existing element. For example, changing the background color of an existing element. Can that be done with the XamlReader? I never used it before.

Comment: Maybe you are refering to skinability. In order to accomplish that u have to use resources. If it is only one element you can get away without entire resource files containing a resource dictionary and using only bindings to resources available for example globally which you change dynamically. If it is for properties for multiple elements you probably will have styles defined in resource dictionaries like in this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22575/WPF-Themes-and-Skins-Engine or at this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19782/Creating-a-Skinned-User-Interface-in-WPF.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that @vitaliyzadorozhnyy suggests is actually doable. We work like this on a regular basis. We load a xaml file which is no other than an xml file, manipulate the xml file and then render a xaml control using

```
XamlReader.Parse(TemplateString);
```

In your case though I think this is not the best solution. Depending on the version of WPF that you need to support you may be better of using the `VisualStateManager`

In general terms you first define a series of VisualStates and then call:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, "stateName", useTransition);
```

To go to the desired configuration based on your int value.

Beware that you need the WPF Toolkit for this to work. There is a good article at:
http://elijahm.ninjuro.com/2012/01/04/visual-states-in-wpf-4-0/

Comment: Would this support defining the visual states after building the application? We don't know at build time which states we will have as they will be defined latter.

Comment: You can create VisualStates dynamically with code, in your case based on the parameters that you define. See this link for an example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a75e15d-7103-4dbd-b31c-a1d9324cabc5/creating-and-using-a-visualstategroup-from-code-behind

Comment: The thing is how to reference an element on the view without naming all the elements on the View so we can reference them from outside.

Comment: WPF has a VisualTree and a LogicalTree that you can traverse, for example by having a root element and going down recursively to all their children, independent of weather they are named or not. There are two classes that help with this: VisualTreeHelper and the LogicalTreeHelper. Take a look at the following: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've thought about this... instead of holding references to all of the relevant controls (which is *not* very MVVM), how about you update these controls using `Bindings`? I have a large scale application and in it, I have a class called `StateManager` which manages the global state of the application. This class uses a `Singleton` pattern and the instance of it is defined in my base view model class. This means that I can access all of its properties from any view model and therefore, any view.

I'm thinking that if you had a similar class, you could put a property in there for each control that you want to affect. For example, you could have `bool` properties that you could set to show or hide various controls (using a `BoolToVisibilityConverter`). You could have `Brush` properties for those controls that you need to change the `Background` property of. You could add your `int` property in there and set each property dependant on the its value.

In the UI, you could bind from each control to the properties in this class:

```
<Button Content="Click" Background="{Binding ConfigurationManager.ButtonBackground}" />
<Label Content="Read" Visibility="{Binding ConfigurationManager.IsLabelVisible, 
    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

In the class, you could update the values:

```
if (YourIntProperty == 1) ButtonBackground = Brushes.Red;
else if (YourIntProperty == 2) IsLabelVisible = false;
else ...
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately it won't work as we don't know at build time which things we will be requested to change so we don't know which properties to bind, it's something to be resolved at runtime.